# Adding a style to every 2nd result for 2 rows, then skipping 2 results?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a bit tricky to word but;

What I'm trying to do is add the style 'background-color: black;' to only some results in my query.

So, if i was to echo my results it would display like this;

```
1st result no style
2nd result black
3rd result black
4th result no style
5th result no style
7th result black
8th result black
9th result no style
10th result no style
```

My query

```
$getusers= $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while($users= $getusers->fetch_assoc()) {

    $color = ??????????????? not sure

    echo '<div style="background-color: ' . $color . ';">';
    echo $users['username'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a placeholder variable.

Follow the progression of `$i` in my example below.

```
$getusers= $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

// Starting at 2 will cause "no style" to happen only once on first pass.
$i = 2; 

while($users= $getusers->fetch_assoc()) {

    // if $i is 3 or 4 value would be "black"
    $rowBg = "background-color:black";

    // Set to an empty string (no style) if $i is 1 or 2.
    if($i <= 2) {
        $rowBg = "";
    }

    $i++;

    // Start over!
    if($i > 4)
        $i = 1;

    echo '<div style="' . $rowBg . ';">';
    echo $users['username'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to ignore the first result giving only the first no style then start the double pattern thing? otherwise my pattern doesn't work properly :(

Comment: @Jayden Then start $i at 2 instead so it skips the first one. Post updated :)

Comment: @Jayden I changed the code from $color to $rowBg since it seems more like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$getusers= $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$r = 1;
while($users= $getusers->fetch_assoc()) {
    $style = ($r == 2 || $r == 3) ? 'style="background-color: black"' : ''; // black for every 2nd & 3rd row
    $r = ($r == 4) ? 1 : $r+1; // reset count to 1 when we get to 4

    echo '<div $style>';
    echo $users['username'];
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
$getusers= $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($users= $getusers->fetch_assoc()) {

$color = "#000000";
if($count == 2 || $count == 3){
echo '<div style="background-color: ' . $color . ';">';

if($count==3){
    $count=0;
}
}
else{
    echo "<div>";
}   
echo $users['username'];

echo '</div>';

$count++;
```

}